# MySQL Shell Scripting to create Procedures

Tags: mysql, macos, shell, creation

I'm working on an install script for Mac OSX and am using a shell script to create a database and all the tables I need for the program to use. The problem that I am facing is the creating of the procedure we need. I have tried multiple way of implementing and wondered if anyone knows of an example or if it is possible. Below is what I have as far as the procedure goes. I would appreciate any help.

The Procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Hours_Procedure()
BEGIN
DECLARE avg_usage FLOAT;
DECLARE max_time TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE counter INTEGER;
DECLARE NumOfNodes INTEGER;
DECLARE Num_Hour_Records INTEGER;

SET counter = 0;
SELECT MAX(Node_Num) INTO NumOfNodes FROM Minutes;

loop1 : LOOP SET avg_usage = 0.0;
 SET counter = counter + 1;
 IF counter = (NumOfNodes + 1) THEN LEAVE loop1;
 ELSE SELECT AVG(x.Power_Usage), MAX(x.Record_Time) INTO avg_usage, max_time FROM(
  SELECT M.Power_Usage, M.Record_Time FROM Minutes M
  WHERE M.Node_Num = counter ORDER BY RID DESC LIMIT 60) x;
  INSERT INTO Hours(Node_Num, Record_Time, Power_Usage) VALUES (counter, max_time, avg_usage);
  DELETE FROM Minutes WHERE Node_Num = counter ORDER BY RID ASC LIMIT 60;
 END IF;
END LOOP loop1;

DROP INDEX Hours_Index ON Hours;
CREATE INDEX Hours_Index ON Hours(RID, Node_Num);
END// DELIMITER ;
```

What I tried:

```
$mysql -u $_adminuser -h $_host -Bse "USE $_hostdb; $createProc;"
```

Where $createProc is the code to create the procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your procedure stored in the file `procedure.sql`, try the following. It eliminates the `USE` statement by specifying the database on the command line:

```
$mysql --batch --silent -u $_adminuser -h $_host $_hostdb < procedure.sql
```

Comment: Any way not in a .sql file though? I don't have access to the directories since the installer package is generated.

Comment: I suspect your problem is due to shell escaping of `\\\` and `;`.  Calling it as a string with `-e` might work if you escape all those characters in the string.  Not sure though.

Comment: Actually I found a way to edit the installer package to hold the .sql file so your solution worked well. Thank you for your help.